# MKMap works incorrect in iOs6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, ios6

I have a problem: I have to know when map data are loaded to the Map view. I used the following method.

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView;
{
    //Some custom code if Map is loaded
}
```

Apple changed Map and now the method is called but map is still loading.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have filed Apple Bug #13774496 related to this and created an example app to show the issue still exists on iOS6: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/MapKitDelegateBug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it. At first, I created a function with my custom code

```
-(void)customCode(id)object
{
    MKMapView* mapView = (MKMapView *)object;
    ...
}
```

In the function mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap I set

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView;
{

    CGFloat systemVersion = [[[ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ];

    if( systemVersion < 6 )
    {
        [self updateMap:mapView];
    }
    else
    {
        [self myMapViewDidFinishLoaded:mapView];
    }
}
```

And

```
-(void)onMapTimed:(id)mapView
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(customCode:) withObject:((NSTimer*)mapView).userInfo waitUntilDone:NO];
    _mapTimer = nil;
}

-(void)myMapViewDidFinishLoaded:(id)mapView;
{
    if(_mapTimer)
    {
        [_mapTimer invalidate];
        [_mapTimer release];
        _mapTimer = nil;
    }
    _mapTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(onMapTimed:) userInfo:mapView repeats:NO];

}
```

It works for me.

Comment: I ran into this same issue today (mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap is called before all the tile have been been displayed properly).  Do you happen to have an example project to help see what you did? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have test project. I have only life project (with NDA, of course). The main idea is to wait about 0.3 second using Timer, if the iOs version 6. I've found excess line in my code and edited it. You may ask me questions if you have them.

Comment: New Map rise - (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView; function when all tiles are loaded. It doesn't mean, the tiles are drawn. In iOs 5 and before it means. You have to wait while the tiles will be drawn. 300 ms is fully enough.

Comment: 300 ms is not always enough. It depends on CPU load, device specs, etc. In certain circumstances fully 2 seconds is not enough.

Comment: This doesn't work for the scenario where you've lost internet connection so it can't load more tiles. It still calls the delegate saying that the map has fully loaded.